# Python render_template asynchronous w/ celery

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, tornado

I am going to make an app where every 200ms, the input value is taken and the python webpage should update. However, `render_template` updates the webpage when run, and therefore hurts the viewer's eyes and deletes the text in such input box. I would rather use `flask` because I am more comfortable in it, but if I need to, can someone point me to resources for `tornado`? For example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_from_directory
import time
a = 0
b = 0
@app.route('/')
app = Flask('app', static_url_path = "/static")
def home():
    return render_template('home-simple.html', a, b)
while 0 == 0:
    a += 1
    #somehow update home-simple.html
    time.sleep(200)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-and-celery/

Comment: You can just use AJAX on the client side if you don't want to reload the full page. A Javascript loop to fetch updates every 200 ms should do the trick.

Comment: @Anye does this mean that you have main.py, which accesses html, which accesses JS, which then accesses main.py?

Comment: Was that to me or to xyres?

Comment: @Anye that was to you.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what it means

Comment: @Anye the code isn't super long. Would it just make more sense to write it in JavaScript instead?

Comment: @Codeitfast, that part is really up to you. Whatever you feel is best for your project and your skills.